Memory efficient alternative to save data with PHP
I have a server and I need to minimize RAM usage. I have to hold billions of records in memory at any time.
Currently I have an array with billions of lines like this:
$test[] = array(

    "xxxxxxxxxx" => rand(100000,900000),
    "aaaaaaaaaa" => rand(100000,900000),
    "bbbbbbbbbb" => rand(100000,900000),
    "cccccccccc" => rand(100000,900000),
    "dddddddddd" => md5(rand(100000,900000)),

);

I discovered that converting the code above to the below, I get about 40% reduction in RAM (tested with memory_get_peak_usage):
$test["xxxxxxxxxx"][] = rand(100000,900000);
$test["aaaaaaaaaa"][] = rand(100000,900000);
$test["bbbbbbbbbb"][] = rand(100000,900000);
$test["cccccccccc"][] = rand(100000,900000);
$test["dddddddddd"][] = md5(rand(100000,900000));

The big problem with the code above is that if I need to remove a "record" from the array, I will have to remove it from the element xxxxxxxxxx, aaaaaaaaaa, bbbbbbbbbb... while in the first code, I just need to literally remove the desired line (I can simply use unset once).
Are you aware of another good way to save data (string and numbers, nothing else: no objects, no inner arrays...) in memory?

Why do you need to store such a large amount of data in memory?

I have a server and I need to minimize RAM usage. I have to hold billions of records in memory at any time. mind elaborating why the heck anyone would need to keep "billions" of of rows in plain array?

I have to hold billions of records in memory....why, exactly? This sounds very much like it's going to be an example of an X-Y Problem

For compliance reasons, we cant hold data on disk and everytime the server is shutdown, an employee from the compliance agency comes to our physical location (where the server is located) and watches my supervisor open a vault (with 2 passwords, one from the supervisor and another from the compliacne agency), plug the NVME to the server, loads data to RAM and puts the NVME back to the vault. We deal with highly sensitive data from Latin American companies and that's the protocol that has avoided lots of problems since I work here (2016).

Ok. That's...unusual. There's no way you can make your server environment more compliant?? After all, your data is on disk, it's just not a disk which is connected to the network most of the time. Anyway...have you considered using a cache tool, maybe?

Realistically "I need to hold billions of items in RAM" and "I need to conserve RAM" are fundamentally contradictory aims, at the end of the day. I guess you could consider using a different programming language, one where you have more direct control over memory management. Back to the 80s... or just C. Or if it's so super-critical to do it like this...just buy more RAM until it's not a problem any more? Might be cheaper than spending all week looking for micro-optimisations

FWIW, the reason the second code uses less memory is that PHP can "pack" an array that's a consecutive list of numbers, which it can't do with string or non-consecutive keys, or complex values like nested arrays. However, without knowing what data you need to hold, and what operations you need to do on it, the question isn't really answerable. There are plenty of different things you could do, but we can't know which would be useable in your application.

@ADyson The company I work for has hundreds of contracts with several companies that forbids it to store any data in disk. That's very explicit in the contract. The contract even states that the NVME will never be kept away from the locked vault for more than 30 minutes, that's a very tight protocol. From all the previous people that worked here before me, they told everybody the data has to be saved using variables in PHP without any framework (opcache and such) to reduce exposure to vulnerabilities in those frameworks (like 0-days).

@IMSoP I said it very clearly in the question that I will only hold numbers and strings, nothing else. No objects, no inner arrays, no classes, no functions...

But how do you keep data in memory? PHP variables are not persistent...

The contract even states...specifying the technical solution down to the letter in the contract... [sighs heavily] ...but yeah, there's nothing you personally can do about that, I would assume.

@Olivier perhaps the script is running on the command-line in a loop so it never dies? Hard to tell, the OP needs to edit the post and provide a bit more context really

@Samul Your question also says that your second code example has a "big problem" to do with "deleting records"; but doesn't define what a "record" is (are they all fixed size? are they indexed by some identifier?), what other operations you need to do on it (random access? sequential access? in-place updates?), and so on. Essentially, you're trying to build an in-memory database in PHP; so you need to first define the constraints of that system. Or, just use an existing, well-tested, implementation, which is less likely to have bugs than something you roll yourself.

Maybe this can be useful.

The first version also seems like it will be difficult to look things up. $test is a sequential array, so you'll need to scan it sequentially to find the element whose subarray contains a key like aaaaaaaaaa. But in the second version you can just use $test['aaaaaaaaaa'] to find it.

@Olivier I cant find a way to understand how using SQLite on RAM would make this less memory intensive, since with PHP I am just using plain variables.

Sometimes we need to delete data from the RAM in very rare cases (client invalidate trust on some data, so we need to delete it immediatly from RAM and when we load again from the NVME all this data is immediatly purged from the NVME storage before being loaded to the RAM). The persistent PHP code is pretty simple:  while(true) {.../dostuff; sleep(1);}

@Samul you said Are you aware of another good way to save data...running a database in memory might be a good way to do it. It might save RAM, and make data operations more efficient too, since databases are already optimised for this sort of thing. Other types of database can also run in memory too.  Simply making an array is a fairly naive solution really - basic doesn't necessarily mean efficient. Have you researched how other people might solve the problem of having substantial amounts of data in memory, in a way that's efficient to access the data as well as use the memory efficiently.

You are using arrays, which are actually complex data structures. They have been optimized in PHP 7, but they are still costly. That being said, I have no idea how much memory SQLite requires (especially if you need indexes).

P.S. It seems odd that this data is so super-important that it can't be stored on a connected disk, yet the job of making that data usable and accessible (presumably in a super-secure way?) has apparently been given over to some home-made command-line script being written (in a language mainly designed for web apps) by someone with no obvious expertise in this area, who is then asking a bunch of PHP generalists fundamental design questions about it on a public forum. Where is the professional solution architect? Where is the security consultant? Where is the project management?

No offence btw - I don't claim to be an expert in this area either, but I do know better than to try and write my own version of something like this, precisely because I know I'm not an expert :-). I know you apparently aren't supposed to use 3rd-party solutions because of the risk of vulnerabilities...but who's to say you won't just write a script which is full of undiscovered bugs as well - and is probably also less efficient? Open-source in particular has succeeded because the source can be publicly examined for bugs, and because it gets well-tested by its communities of users.

OTOH if you buy in something proprietary you can then more easily insure against the risk of vulnerabilities, or ensure the supplier has such indemnity that covers you. And of course you have their commercial resources backing it, to help fix problems. Just some food for thought.

"I am just using plain variables" What you call "plain variables" are much more complex than you think (again, optimized in PHP 7, but still costly).

A memory-efficient way to store data in PHP is to use pack(). For example, to store a list of three 16-bit integers, you can use pack('s3', 1, 2, 3), which returns a string of 6 bytes only.

I'm confused by your statement, "I can simply use unset once" You can do that in both cases. If you do unset($test["cccccccccc"]); in the second example, it will remove everything under that key, you don't have to individually iterate over subkeys.

Would a ramdisk be a possible solution for this? Use standard OS permissions to isolate the user to just that in order to guarantee that nothing can be copied where it shouldn't. You can then treat this as a regular file, or probably better a collection of smaller files.
